# Process name is coming as "[System Process]"

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I am using following code to enumerate all process in windows 7 32 bit machine . But most of processes name appearing as ie szExeFile = "[System Process]" and I am not able to get name of the processes.
any idea how to resolve this?

```
 PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
 HANDLE hSnap= CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
 if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
  procEntry.dwSize= sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
  if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
  {
   do
      { 
           MessageBox(NULL,procEntry.szExeFile,L"",MB_OK);
       }while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));
  }
```

Comment: There's *one* process with that name.  It is a fake entry to represent the Windows kernel.  It doesn't have a real EXE file, you'll need to skip it.

Comment: But during enumeration I am not able to other processes, its working fine on my laptop but not enumerating all processes on virtual machine.

Comment: There's a bug in your VM, get another one.